# How do I get a count of the number of objects in a json array that lives in a BigQuery table?

Tags: json, count, google-bigquery

I am querying a table in BigQuery that has columns `Id` (integer) and `user_json` (string).
`user_json` is a json array structured like so:
{
"user_id": "123456",
"is_deleted": false,
"address_book":
{
"uaddr_Qi6vCZ3a":
{
"city": "Nowhere",
"state": "CA",
"last_name": "Smith",
"first_name": "John",
"postal_code": "99999",
"iso2_country": "US",
"phone_number": "1234567809",
"address_line_1": "123 Spring Drive",
"address_line_2": "Apt 101",
"address_book_item_id": "uaddr_Qi6vCZ3a"
},
"uaddr_hZxdzoOE":
{
"city": "Somewhere",
"state": "NV",
"last_name": "Smith",
"first_name": "John",
"postal_code": "88888",
"iso2_country": "US",
"phone_number": "9087654321",
"address_line_1": "321 Fall Blvd",
"address_book_item_id": "uaddr_hZxdzoOE"
}
}
}

I need to find the number of address for each `Id`. The "uaddr_xxxx " is unique for each "address_book" entry. I would like be able to count how many "uaddr_xxxx " are in `user_json` for each unique `Id`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select id,
  array_length(regexp_extract_all(user_json, r'"(uaddr_[^"]+)":')) uaddr_count,
  regexp_extract_all(user_json, r'"(uaddr_[^"]+)":') uaddr_items
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]